# Column count doesn't match value count? But it does

Tags: mysql

```
    CREATE TABLE invoices(
    invoice_id          INT             PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id         INT             NOT NULL,
    supplier_id         INT             NOT NULL,
    invoice_due_date    VARCHAR(12),
    invoice_supplier    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    invoice_contact     VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    invoice_amount      INT,
    invoice_paid        BOOL            DEFAULT FALSE,

    CONSTRAINT invoice_fk_supplier
        FOREIGN KEY(supplier_id)
        REFERENCES suppliers(supplier_id),

    CONSTRAINT invoice_fk_category
        FOREIGN KEY(category_id)
        REFERENCES categories(category_id)
    );

    INSERT INTO invoices(invoice_id, category_id, supplier_id, 
    invoice_supplier, invoice_due_date, invoice_contact, invoice_amount, 
    invoice_paid) VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, "Pepsi" '12-24-2017', 'James Hatfield', 23500, FALSE),
    (2, 2, 2, "Ragu", '12-20-2017', 'Mike Richards', 8650, FALSE),
    (3, 2, 3, "Miguel's Produce", '12-18-2017', 'Miguel Profesa', 6750, 
    FALSE),
    (4, 2, 4, "Butch's Butcher Shop", '12-15-2017', 'Rick Santana', 9550, 
    FALSE),
    (5, 2, 5, "Cafe Carmen", '12-04-2017', 'Carmen San Diego', 1250, FALSE);
```

I am using MySQL WorkBench 6.3, and I keep getting this error

> "**Error Code:** 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

whenever I am trying to run my INSERT statement to add data to the database.  I have no issues with my other tables, only this one.  However, when I was looking up this error, it seems that many times the error comes down to not having a matching number of values to the records, but I have triple checked that I have 8 fields and 8 values.

If anyone could help me out or explain it at all, it would be much appreciated as this has had me stumped for a few hours.

Cheers!

Comment: dont insert primary key...let it auto incremenet

Comment: is the supplier & category table already populated ?? are the FK correct

Comment: Yes, both tables are successfully populated and both foreign keys are correct.

Comment: Foreign Keys are correct, I tried removing one of my foreign keys, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First and foremost**  "Pepsi" '12-24-2017' has no comma in between ..typo error

(1, 2, 1, "Pepsi" '12-24-2017', 'James Hatfield', 23500, FALSE),

**SEcondly**  *your fourth column is  VARCHAR(12) & not  VARCHAR(255)*

Primary key insertion has a lot of conflict...to be on safe side...keep PK auto

```
 CREATE TABLE invoices(
    invoice_id          INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id         INT             NOT NULL,
    supplier_id         INT             NOT NULL,
    invoice_due_date    VARCHAR(255),
    invoice_supplier    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    invoice_contact     VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    invoice_amount      INT,
    invoice_paid        BOOL            DEFAULT FALSE,

    CONSTRAINT invoice_fk_supplier
        FOREIGN KEY(supplier_id)
        REFERENCES suppliers(supplier_id),

    CONSTRAINT invoice_fk_category
        FOREIGN KEY(category_id)
        REFERENCES categories(category_id)
    );
```

and then do an insert like..

```
   INSERT INTO invoices( category_id, supplier_id, 
    invoice_supplier, invoice_due_date, invoice_contact, invoice_amount, 
    invoice_paid) VALUES
    ( 2, 1, "Pepsi", "12-24-2017", "James Hatfield", 23500, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and clear explanation!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: please recheck the answer...i have got the issue...check the first and foremost part :p

Comment: did you get that comma missing after pepsi ??

Comment: Yes, I did not see the comment above, thank you again!
'